# How to extract particular groups in a shell script?

Tags: git, shell, grep, zsh

I am trying to extract project name and the version from the git tag information. An example tag looks like this: `atlantis/v12`. We need to seperate out the first group as project name, ie. `atlantis` and second as version ie. `v12`.

Trying to do this `git describe --tag | grep -P (.*).*(v[0-9]*)| awk {1}` results in `zsh: unknown file attribute: v`, and with bash `syntax error near unexpected token` ('`. I need help understanding what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to quote the argument of `-P` in grep, and zsh considers it its duty to attempt filename expansion on them. You have to write it as

```
grep -P '(.*).*(v[0-9]*)'
```

Aside from this, your regexp says: Match zero or more characters of anything, followed by zero or more characters of anything, followed by zero or more of those strings which consist of a `v` with zero or more digits added. Hence your regexp would match any line in the input.

Comment: This is still being considered as wrong usage with it showing all the available options for grep

Comment: Well, it explains the _unknown file attribute_. The regexp itself does not make much sense either, since it would trivially match every line. But this would lead to a new question, if you  can't figure it out by yourself.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it somehow with `sed`?

Comment: @AdityaKumarGupta: In your question, you specifically asked where the error comes from which you encountered. While I don't see why you don't want to stick with _grep_ and just get the pattern right, I would in any case ask this in a **new** question and not discuss these issues in a comment. In any case you would need to describe the full line of the input string, and not only how the pattern looks like which you want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using awk:

```
git describe --tag | awk -F\/ '{ print "Project: "$1;print "Version: "$2 }'
```

Set the field delimited to "/" and then print the first field as the project and the second as the version.